# @types/forge-apis/index.d.ts' is not a module

Tags: typescript, autodesk-forge

I always get an error message while importing the AuthClientTwoLegged class from the @types/forge-apis

```
import { AuthClientTwoLegged} from 'forge-apis';
```

...

```
var oAuth2TwoLegged = new AuthClientTwoLegged(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, [
  'data:read',
  'data:write'
]);
```

The type is defined in the tsconfic.json:

```
"types": ["forge-viewer", "forge-apis"]
```

Comment: Did you install `@types/forge-apis` as your dev dependency?

Comment: Yes, it is installed as dev dependency

Comment: Error message: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'forge-apis' in `

Comment: what is your typescript version? 2.0+ or ...?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project is configured properly with:

- install `@types/forge-apis` as dev dependency.
- Compile with Typescript 2 and onwards.
- You dont exactly need to explicitly specify `forge-apis` in your `tsconfig` as its definition the same name as the package.

See this sample repo [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-nodejs-typeview.sample) for reference and you can see it is passing build so you can be confident to base your project on it.